# Nested enumerate items are missing some periods when cross-referencing

Tags: hyperref, enumerate, labels

I am writing a rulebook and need to reference clauses and sub-clauses throughout.

When I have a nested enumerate item to the level of 5.4.2.3, the cross-reference displays as 5.4.2.23.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Rulebook}
\section{Footwear Rules}
\begin{enumerate}[\thesection .1.]
\item No running.\label{itm:running}
   \begin{enumerate}[\thesection.\ref{itm:running}.1.]
   \item Running is punishable by death.
   \end{enumerate}

\item Each person shall be responsible for: \label{itm:duty}
  \begin{enumerate}[\thesection.\ref{itm:duty}.1.]
  \item Clean shoes.
  \item Clean socks.
  \item Tied laces.\label{itm:socks}
  \end{enumerate}

\item Applications for new shoes shall be sent to the Dean.\label{itm:new}
  \begin{enumerate}[\thesection.\ref{itm:new}.1.]
  \item Applications shall:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item Indicate the name of the applicants;
   \item Indicate any instances when the applicant has broken Rule \thesection.\ref{itm:duty}.\ref{itm:socks}.
   %The above item contains the offending \ref
   \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This code gives me the output of:
[image]

What can I do to make the reference show up as "Rule 1.1.2.3."?

I am compiling in terminal with

```
$ latex file.tex
$ latex file.tex
$ dvips file.dvi
```

Comment: Clearly this has to do something with the stuff in brackets (designed to incorporate section numbers) after you start the lists. If they are removed, then the list turns into the standard 2. (a) ... (b) ... (c) ..., and the item reference prints out “2c” without an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses only lower-level LaTeX macros, and no packages. The macros are called `\theenumi`, `\labelenumi`, `\theenumii`, `\labelenumii`, and `\p@enumii`.

Use `\label` and `\ref` on enumerated items as you would for any other (LaTeX) object. Of course, you can still load the `enumerate` package if you wish.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

%%\usepackage{enumerate}  %% not needed
\renewcommand\theenumi{\thesection.\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\theenumii.}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumii{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Rulebook}
\section{Footwear Rules}
\begin{enumerate}%%[\thesection .1.]  %% not needed
\item No running.\label{itm:running}
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item Running is punishable by death.
   \end{enumerate}

\item Each person shall be responsible for: \label{itm:duty}
  \begin{enumerate}%%[\thesection.\ref{itm:duty}.1.] %% not needed
  \item Clean shoes.
  \item Clean socks.
  \item Tied laces.\label{itm:socks}
  \end{enumerate}

\item Applications for new shoes shall be sent to the Dean.\label{itm:new}
  \begin{enumerate}%%[\thesection.\ref{itm:new}.1.] %% not needed
  \item Applications shall:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item Indicate the name of the applicants;
   \item Indicate any instances when the applicant has broken Rule \ref{itm:socks}.
   %%The above item no longer contains an offending \ref
   \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The same effect could be achieved by loading the `chngcntr` package and executing the following instructions:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{enumi}{section}
\counterwithin{enumii}{enumi}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}   % add a "dot" after '\theenumi'
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\theenumii.} % add a "dot" after '\theenumii'
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@enumii{} % remove the "prefix" from `enumii` in cross-references
\makeatother
```

Comment: @Psymon343 - Thanks for letting me know that this answer helped. By the way, the first solution assumes that no enumerations will be carried out across sections. Do let me know if this assumption isn't valid, i.e., if it may be the case that `enumerate` environments could span `section`-level divisions. If that were the case, the `enumi` counter should be "chained" more directly to the `section` counter; this could be accomplished by adding two additional instructions. In contrast, no additional instructions would be needed if one employs the second, `chngcntr`-based solution. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking if I have any `\section` or `\subsection` called inside an enumerate list?

Comment: @Psymon343 - Yes. :-)

Comment: That's not what I was trying to do, no! :) but thanks for making sure for anyone else who might use this thread for help.